# How select specifics files in grep

Tags: grep

So. I have to grep a string in a dir that contains files with same name except for hours:

i.e.

- filename_01_WORD-1.log
- filename_02_WORD-1.log
- filename_03_WORD-1.log
- filename_04_WORD-1.log
- filename_05_WORD-1.log
- ...
- filename_23_WORD-1.log
- filename_24_WORD-1.log

I'm trying to grep a single word 'ABC' in just files of hours between 18 and 23.

I've tried with `grep 'ABC' filename_[18-19-20-21-22-23]*WORD*.log` but it is expanded as grep on files from 05 to 23 and I don't know why.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find files based on filename range?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/175929) or [Find all folders starting with number range](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269103)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use brace expansion instead:

```
grep ABC filename_{18,19,20,21,22,23}_WORD*.log
```

or more compactly

```
grep ABC filename_{18..23}_WORD*.log
```

The way you've written it tells the shell to consider any file starting with `filename_`, followed by a single character matching one of the set `1`, `8` to `1` (which doesn't match anything), `9` to `2` (likewise), `0` to `2`, `1` to `2`, `2` to `2` or `3` (so in the end, `0`, `1`, `2` or `3`), followed by any characters, followed by `WORD` etc.

Comment: Ah... you beat me to it with a minute!

Comment: Thank you alot for all your effort on making me understand.